# SpringBoot Actuator version 1.X readiness and liveness probes

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, kubernetes, spring-boot-actuator

I'm exploring options to activate readiness and liveness probes for SpringBoot 1.X. It's essential to have both endpoints enabled for seamless Kubernetes deployments. Any insights on achieving this?

```
/actuator/health/liveness
/actuator/health/readiness
```

Is it feasible to obtain those features in the upcoming Spring version, or should I proceed with implementing them myself?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring Boot 1.5 was [end-of-lifed in 2019](https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support).  Do you really mean this very old version of Spring, or something newer?

Comment: I don't have an option, I need 1.X. I'm working on a legacy app that is migrating to Kubernetes.

Answer (score 0):

if someone needs the same, that's the final code I came up:

For the **Kubernetes Health Indicator:**

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthAggregator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.Assert;

import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Map;

@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
public class KubernetesHealthIndicator implements HealthIndicator {
  
  private final HealthAggregator healthAggregator;
  
  private final Map<String, HealthIndicator> healthIndicators;
  
  @Override
  public Health health() {
    Assert.notNull(healthAggregator, "HealthAggregator must not be null");
    Assert.notNull(healthIndicators, "HealthIndicators must not be null");
    CompositeHealthIndicator healthIndicator = new CompositeHealthIndicator(healthAggregator);
    for (Map.Entry<String, HealthIndicator> entry : healthIndicators.entrySet()) {
      healthIndicator.addHealthIndicator(getKey(entry.getKey()), entry.getValue());
    }
    
    return healthIndicator.health();
  }
  
  private String getKey(String name) {
    int index = name.toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).indexOf("healthindicator");
    if (index > 0) {
      return name.substring(0, index);
    }
    
    return name;
  }
}
```

For the **KubernetesHeathCheckController**:

```
import lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@RequestMapping(value = "/actuator/health", produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
public class KubernetesHealthCheckController {
  
  private final KubernetesHealthIndicator kubernetesHealthIndicator;
  
  @GetMapping("/liveness")
  public Health liveness() {
    return kubernetesHealthIndicator.health();
  }
  
  @GetMapping("/readiness")
  public Health readiness() {
    return kubernetesHealthIndicator.health();
  }
}
```